# How to install package "wordcloud" in python?

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am trying to install wordcloud in my system using pip. But i have received the below mentioned error. I tried many ways to install but I failed. hope any one from you can help me.

```
C:\Users\AVATAR>pip install wordcloud
Collecting wordcloud
  Using cached wordcloud-1.6.0.tar.gz (214 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (6.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (3.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib->wordcloud) (40.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\avatar\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: wordcloud
    Running setup.py install for wordcloud ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AVATAR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-resmy70s\\wordcloud\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AVATAR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-resmy70s\\wordcloud\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AVATAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fq23o1gz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python\Include\wordcloud'
         cwd: C:\Users\AVATAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-resmy70s\wordcloud\
    Complete output (20 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\color_from_image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\tokenization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\wordcloud.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\wordcloud_cli.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\stopwords -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\DroidSansMono.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud
    UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud/_version.py
    set build\lib.win32-3.7\wordcloud/_version.py to '1.6.0'
    running build_ext
    building 'wordcloud.query_integral_image' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AVATAR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-resmy70s\\wordcloud\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AVATAR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-resmy70s\\wordcloud\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AVATAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fq23o1gz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python\Include\wordcloud' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: For future reference, please copy the error text itself rather than including a screenshot. For your immediate problem, you have to install [MS Visual C++ 14.0 build tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) and have it be in your `PATH` because `wordcloud` depends on some C or C++ code.

Comment: from the message error shown it requires some dependencies in visual studio.Have you tried to install visual studio and re-rerun the pip install command?

Comment: @YehdhihANNA Yes I tried installing Visual Studio and re-running the pip command but it didn't worked.

Comment: @wkl I installed MS Visual C++ build tools and tried executing pip command but still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a virtual environment in python and then try `pip install wordcloud`.

If creating virtual environment doesn't work. Try installing anaconda :

- install Anaconda
- open anaconda terminal
- install wordcloud using pip command
- launch IDE from anaconda
- Run program from IDE's terminal

and Done...

Answer (score 2):

### **How to install wordcloud**

1. Check for the version of wordcloud available for the version of python and operating system you are using visiting this link: https://pypi.org/project/wordcloud/#history
2. install wordcloud using below code:

   pip install wordcloud -version-compatible-operatingsystem

Another method to install wordcloud

1. In Anaconda prompt
2. conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud

Answer (score 1):

In the Anaconda prompt, enter:
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge wordcloud

After this, start python shell, and try to import the wordcloud module. It should be imported successfully

Answer (score 0):

Just download wordcloud_version_for_your_config.whl from pypip, then install it manually from CMD:

```
pip install 'path_to_file/wordcloud_version_for_your_config.whl'
```