# Install packages such as Wordcloud for Python: what tools to be installed?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, jupyter-lab, word-cloud

when trying to install packages such as wordcloud, I get the error message
`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`. When following the link, the installer proposes many different options. Just selecting the C++ requires almost 7GB.
Could you help me choose the bare minimum options required to install wordcloud? Indeed I have a small config, and would rather avoid using so much space for a small package (and for the moment, I don't plan using Visual Studio except for that matter). Thanks!

Comment: This looks to have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66548975/10437959).

Comment: I did as mentionned in the link: download, run the exe and click install: same message. There must be some boxes to be checked, but I don't know which ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed the information in the instruction for setup with Python found [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Compilers_Installation_and_configuration)?

It indicates that you should update setuptools `pip install --upgrade setuptools` before doing anything else.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I installed the 7Go, I guess there is no alternative...